# How to know the radio size for a Toyota Corolla 2018?

Tags: audio

I want to buy an aftermarket stereo for my Toyota Corolla 2018 SE, and on some website to check compatibility, I have the choice of a 6 inches, or a 7 inches stereo. I really don't know what this measure is, and how to determine which is correct.

How to check the radio size of my car?

Comment: Take out the existing radio and measure the hole.